# Sync React.component state with local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a function that would grab the state of a component from local storage if it exists (if it has been saved before).     It would be a function that could be used by all the components, something like:

```
    // my util function 
    myFunction = (componentUniqueIdentifier, componentState) => {

    // for all the keys found in componentState, try to find in local storage if localStorage[componentUniqueIdentifier][key] exists. if it exists, override value.


if(localStorage.getItem(key)) { componentState[key] = localStorage.getItem(key); }

return componentState;

    }
```

and more importantly:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {

    state = {
      thisIsAKey: ''
    }

    render() {

        console.log(this.state.thisIsAKey); // this shows value coming from local storage if found

        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }

}

export default Test;
```

So obviously it wont be that simple and I will probs have to change a few things, but the idea would be to create this function that would sync the state of ALL the components with local storage, so I dont have to write this logic again when building a new component.

So far I havent been able to come up with any good idea... I have been looking into mixins or creating a HOC that all my components would extends but is it a good way to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to save the state of the entire application then I recommend using [redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html). Then whenever there are changes to your state (or store in redux) you can stringify it and save it to localStorage.

Comment: Thank you AndreasLengkeek. We are already using Redux of course, but we need to (we really do) store the state of each component separately within the local storage and to be able to re-render them as they were if the user closes the browser and open it again for instance. Do you think that "syncing" the state of these components to the redux store would be a good solution?